# jax-rs configuring several endpoints

Tags: spring, cxf, jax-rs

if i want to have several endpoints for example "/" and "/services" can i configure it with several server defenitions? 
i found in docs that it's possible ([docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-Multipleendpointsandresourceclasses))
 but it doesn't work for me, i got working only one endpoint and always 404 error responsing for another
part of my application context:

```
<jaxrs:server id="service1" address="http://localhost:${server.port}/blabla" basePackages="com.service1">
    <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>

<jaxrs:server id="service2" address="http://localhost:${server.port}" basePackages="com.service2">
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Comment: I think that you should declare `<jaxrs:serviceBeans>` that implements your endpoint. Furthermore the address should be either `address="/"` or `address="/blabla" `

Comment: doesn't it autodiscovers service beans annotated with @path from basePackages?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It take only `@Provider`.